# MySQL search as date_format not working

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my database as TEXT (I know I should use date but this field could have more values than only date). As they are only a few, it won't take off performance.

My problem is the query, since it always return no values. But if I make the query manually it works well. I think it must be something with the query in prepared statements but can't get it.

```
$date = date("d/m/Y");
$query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE DATE_FORMAT(expiredate, '%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(?, '%d/%m/%Y') && id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM adsfixed ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
```

The query is supposed to get a random row in projects table where column expiredate is bigger or equal than today in d/m/Y format (don't know if the logic is OK, so I try to explain what I need).

Comment: Do not compare strings (with date). You must compare the dates

Comment: And how can I do it since the field is string and I need to search it as a date?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: ANY query that works manually, works with a prepared statement. It means you are running NOT THE SAME query.

Comment: I needed to change the query to use the date instead DATE_FORMAT(?, '%d/%m/%Y')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the Parameter to date not the date to string:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE Date(expiredate) >= str_to_date(?, '%d/%m/%Y') && id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM adsfixed ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: *It doesn't work.* means? Any error message or wrong data?

Comment: It doesn't return any value but should since I have a record in the table where expiredate is 05/11/2017.

Comment: @Tiago Have you checked, that the data you bind are which you expected?

Comment: Already found the problem. Since my column is TEXT as stated above, I couldn't make the query as DATE or DATE_FORMAT. I used your information and made some changes. Used the function str_to_date in both forms and it works right now. Thanks! "WHERE str_to_date(expiredate, '%d/%m/%Y') >= str_to_date(?, '%d/%m/%Y')  && id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM adsfixed ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1"

Comment: @Tiago it is no good db design to store Dates as text. I would Change that

Comment: I know it's not a good db design. But since the same field could have text, this would be the best way to achieve it. Since it would have only 10/20 records, it would be so bad?